# How to publish an Extension to Azure FHIR repository?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am using **Azure API for FHIR**. I have a `Claims` payload that requires some additional fields, which I am adding to the `extension` structure like:

```
extension: [
    {
        "url": "ROW_ID",
        "valueString": "1"
    },
    {
        "url": "LOB",
        "valueString": "MAPD"
    }
]
```

To perform a search on *ROW_ID*, and *LOB*, I need to publish this **extension** which I would be using in my `SearchParameter`.
How and where do I publish the extension ?

Answer (score 1):

To publish an extension, you post the structure definition to your FHIR server. In addition, if you need to search for it you will need to create a custom search parameter and reindex the database. You can read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/how-to-do-custom-search

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.